# PHP difference between terminal and browser

Tags: php, pear, neo4j, phar

There is Neo4J installed on my Ubuntu and I'm running a test code. It's perfectly working when the code runs on terminal such as:

```
root@ekin-Inspiron-1090:/var/www# php neo.php
home: demolished
name: Arthur Dent
```

But when it comes to run on browser like localhost/neo.php, it gives fatal error and stops working.

```
Warning: require(phar://neo4jphp.phar): failed to open stream: operation failed in /var/www/neo.php on line 4 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'phar://neo4jphp.phar' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/neo.php on line 4
```

I don't think it's really something with Neo4J or its PHP driver. What should be the reason?

edit: by the way, there are two php.ini files; i think one for apache and one for command line. I checked both of them and phar extension paths are the same. Also there are no include_path settings in both of them.

Comment: It might be saying you don't have access to the file.

Comment: command line runs under YOUR user id, apache runs under its own userid. Make sure that the apache user has access to the phar file.

Comment: Seems likely to be a permission issue since the example shows the user running as `root`.

Comment: @MarcB, how can I change the permission of apache user to the phar file?

Comment: @MarcB, thank you so much! I've been trying hard to solve this for 3 days. I give my apache user (www-data) to access /var/www and it solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an authorization error. Apache runs under its own user, so you need to give apache user to access `www` folder.